# Setting table td element to a custom angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to update a td of a table to utilise a custom angularjs directive.

I have tried `td.innerHtml = "<my-directive></my-directive>"` and the html for myDirective is

`<div>hi</div>`

The directive code has

`replace: true,`

When I inspect the element I have `td.innerHtml = "<my-directive></my-directive>"` and not`<div>hi</div>`

How can I change a table td element to use a custom directive.

Comment: If you're doing DOM manipulation with angular, you're doing something wrong. What's the problem with just putting `<td><my-directive></my-directive></td>` in the template?

Comment: You can't inject directive tags or attributes yourself without using `$compile`. Let angular do it for you using `template` or `templateUrl` properties of directive as already mentioned

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I am using a 3rd party control (Hansontable) to create the Excel like grid. Then based on the data I have for a particular cell I want to change the table cell (td) to, for example, display a chart (in a custom directive) or have a form of data (in a custom directive etc).

Answer (score 0):

## Angular Limitations

Angular cannot respond to DOM changes that occur after the application is loaded, to do so would cause severe performance issues within the application. In order to resolve this you should limit DOM changes to those that occur within the angular application.

## Workaround

If for whatever reason you MUST edit the DOM outside of the angular scope you can compile the elements manually using

```
$compile(html)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried $compile(html)($scope). When I inspect the td element I see <my-directive></my-directive> but not myDirective's template. The controller for  myDirective is also not called.